# Simple PurgeCSS

Tags: javascript, css, sass

hope somebody can help me, I used to use purgecss like the code below, but now with the new version of purge, Im getting this error "error: unknown option '--out'"

**filename: purgecss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['*.php', '*/*.php', '*.js', '*/*.js','assets/js/yepes-restrepo-min.js'],
  css: ['assets/css/yepes-restrepo.css'],
  whitelist: ['body', 'body-inner', 'home_body','bg-success','fa-times']
}
```

and this is the code I use in the terminal:
purgecss --config ./purgecss.config.js --out assets/css/

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PurgeCSS v2 and above uses `--output` rather than `--out`

Try: `purgecss --config ./purgecss.config.js --output assets/css/`

You can find more on [PurgeCSS CLI](https://purgecss.com/CLI.html)